# Get duplicate id's with same desc

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two fields, ID and Description. I have many rows in said table. I want to know how many times an id with the same description is repeated.

For example:

```
ID | Description
23 | Key
24 | Desk
25 | Key
26 | Key
27 | Desk
```

And I want to make a sql query which I get the number of times that a Description is repeated, the id that are associated and the own Description.

How can I solve this?

The output that I want it follows like this:

```
ID | Description | Occurrences
23 | Key | 3
24 | Desk | 2
25 | Key | 3
26 | Key | 3
27 | Desk | 2
```

Sorry if I have not explained well. I want to know number of occurrences of the same Description with the ID's.

Wish your answers. Bests regards to all.

Comment: Group by desc, group_concat id, count(*)

Comment: nb desc is a reserved word in mysql and should be backticked.

Comment: The sample you've shared does not contain any duplicated IDs. Can you share any input that matches your description?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would go with the [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) solution suggested above, but this will give the output you requested using [COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) as a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Description) AS Occurrences
    FROM your_table
) t
WHERE Occurrences > 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

If you want to see all descriptions, not just the duplicated ones, you can drop the use of the subquery:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Description) AS Occurrences
FROM your_table
ORDER BY ID;
```

The same can be achieved with a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE Description = t.Description) AS Occurrences
FROM your_table t
HAVING Occurrences > 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

The `HAVING` clause can be dropped if you want to include the descriptions which are not duplicated.

All three will produce the same output for the sample data provided:

| ID | Description | Occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | Key | 3 |
| 24 | Desk | 2 |
| 25 | Key | 3 |
| 26 | Key | 3 |
| 27 | Desk | 2 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8zHsdLSw)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you can run this:

```
Select id, Desc, count(*)
from yourtable
group by Desc
Having count(*) > 1
```

This query will provide you the results of the times a Desc is in the specific table.

Comment: OP also wants 'the id that are associated'

Comment: i guess putting the id will also work. not sure if this fails in the group by clause.

Comment: this will always fail as DESC is a reserved word

Comment: `id` is not functionally dependent on `Desc`, so should not be in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a query like this. It also show the duplicate ids.

```
Select count(*) AS cnt, `Desc`, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) as IDs
from yourTable
group by `Desc`
Having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: all `desc` have to be backticked